# how to change background color of the navigation bar and navigation text color

Tags: ios, ios7, rubymotion

I want the background color of the navigation bar to be black and the text on the navigation bar to be white.

Everything looks fine on my simulator as shown below:

[image]

However, when I test it on the actual device w/ 7.1, even though the background color of navigation bar is orange, the title of the screen is black.

This is what I'm doing in my application delegate:

```
@window.rootViewController = UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(main_controller)
@window.rootViewController.navigationBar.barTintColor = '#DF533B'.to_color
@window.rootViewController.navigationBar.translucent = true
@window.rootViewController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor
@window.rootViewController.navigationBar.setTitleTextAttributes({
    UITextAttributeTextColor => UIColor.whiteColor
})
```

my `deployment_target` is `7.0` and `app.sdk_version` is `7.1`

Should I be putting this code in `viewDidLoad` of all my controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with RubyMotion, but you should use the UIAppearance proxy:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[self navBarColor]];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[self navBarTitleColor]];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [self navBarTitleColor], NSFontAttributeName : [self titleFont]}];
```

You should do this before you load your main window in your AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Moby's answer which appears correct to me, Make sure you add it to the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions for your app delegate.